# Can I get javascript to automatically click on a link on another page once that page loads?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, load, click

I want to create a link on page A that links to page B and also clicks on a link on page B once page B has finished loading. Is this possible or would I have to code javascript on that specific page where the link is supposed to be clicked on.

Comment: yes (option two) You can't click a link on another page with js

Comment: aww, why'd I get a minus vote on my question? I'm trying to make a javascript code for a client who posts car ads on craigslist and wants a link on his ad to directly open a form on his own website.

Comment: thanks for removing the minus vote, whoever it was =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want to redirect to another page you can check the `document.referrer` on your site to see where the person came from (url) and then redirect with `location.replace("http://example.com/myformpage.htm")`

Comment: is there a way I can create a 'get' parameter or give some way to trigger a javascript function on my second web page? I know how to do it in php but my client isn't using php right now and I'm trying to figure out a work around using javascript.

Comment: maybe with ajax you van "get" the form and submit it if it's the same domain, but I'm not experienced in that area so I wouldn't know much about it

Comment: using the document.referrer method you mentioned, would I be able to allow a certain javascript function to run if say the user is coming from any sublink of craigslist.com?

Comment: Certainly! `document.referrer`  just returns the url of the page you came from. you can then use regex in your decision logic to isolate the domain and subdomain.

Comment: thank you very much Joseph, I'll be looking into document.referrer then. cheers.

Comment: @Qlidnaque glad to help :) if you have any questions in implementing it, don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, JS is pretty much run in contained environment (i.e., the original page).