# Simulate a click from a link on another internal page

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have four images with links on my [main page](https://debora.com.au). I also have four matching galleries on [another page](https://debora.com.au/gallery) that are hidden except for one at a time. Each gallery is shown when a specific image on that gallery page is clicked.

I am trying to get the home page images to link specifically to their corresponding galleries (such as clicking on the children image on the home page, will loadup the gallery page and display the children gallery).

I read these questions and tried to implement their answers:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847185](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847185/how-to-programmatically-trigger-the-click-on-a-link-using-jquery)

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7047746](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7047746/can-i-get-javascript-to-automatically-click-on-a-link-on-another-page-once-that)

The gallery page loads up using a carousel plugin and a custom script for my setup was created to allow the images/tabs(the class is img.imgslide and they do not have any ID property) on the carousel to show/hide galleries:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        if (jQuery('.customtabs > br').length) {
            jQuery('.customtabs > br').remove();
        }       
});

function displaycustom_tab(obj) {
        var totalSlides = jQuery(obj).parent().find('>div').length / 3;
        var tabi = 0;
        var slidei = jQuery(obj).index() + 1;
        if (slidei > (2 * totalSlides)) {
            tabi = slidei - (2 * totalSlides);
        } else if (slidei > (totalSlides)) {
            tabi = slidei - totalSlides;
        } else {
            tabi = slidei;
        }
        tabi--;
        jQuery('.customtabs > div').removeClass('activetab');
        jQuery('.customtabs > div:eq(' + tabi + ')').addClass('activetab');
    jQuery(window).trigger('resize');
}
```

**I tried to use this code:** The text wrapped with *s is my added code (with the *s).

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        if (jQuery('.customtabs > br').length) {
            jQuery('.customtabs > br').remove();
        }       
        ****jQuery('#newborn').get(0).click();****
});
```

I get this **error in Chromes Inspect panel**:

*gallery.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined*

I'm not sure how to get this working. Do I need to create an attribute property for the ID field on the carousel tabs?

Comment: does `#newborn` exist?

Comment: Moving away to a new page, you will need to pass which tab/group was selected in the first page so you can perform the action on gallery page.... links will be something like this /gallery?slidegroup=children. is this happening already ?

Comment: Thank you for your response @Searching. No I'm not doing that at all, I just have this:

<a href="https://debora.com.au/gallery#children">&nbsp;
<h2>Children
Photography</h2></a>

How do I implement that code? Is that javascript or html?

Comment: You really need to use url for this for both bookmarking and SEO purposes. Each gallery should also have it's own page title , social meta tags etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looked through the source of the link you posted.  Looks like you might be using the wrong ID.

```
jQuery('#newborn').get(0).click();
```

should be

```
jQuery('#newbornlink').get(0).click();
```